# SignalR client not receiving messages in integration tests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I am trying to test my SignalR connections in my integration tests.
The client looks like this:

```cs
var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                     .WithUrl(
                        $"{client.BaseAddress}meeting-notifications",
                         o =>
                         {
                             o.HttpMessageHandlerFactory = _ => Server?.CreateHandler();
                         })
                     .Build();

connection.On<BoardDto>("BoardStateChanged", board => { Do Something... });

await connection.StartAsync();
```

I am calling the method in my ASP-NET Core backend like so:

```cs
public async Task BroadcastBoardStateAsync(int boardId, BoardDto board)
{
    await _notificationHub.Clients.All.BoardStateChanged(board);
}
```

The client is able to call a method on the server but not the other way around.
Does anyone know what I am missing here?

Edit: I debugged the server call and the `_notificationHub` contains the connection-id of the client.

Comment: Why are you assigning a `HttpMessageHandlerFactory`? The way the code is written, if `Server` is null there won't be any handler. Have you tried the code *without* the options callback? You can handle the connection's events to see if disconnects for some reason

Comment: Sorry if this was unclear. The ``Server`` is the TestServer under which the integration test is running. This call is needed as without it the connection of the client is refused.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out SignalR v3.x does json serialization via `System.Text.Json` which had some problem with my `POCO's`.
To fix this, I had to explicitly tell SignalR to use NewtonsoftJson for serialization via this method call:

```cs
var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                     .WithUrl(
                         $"{client.BaseAddress}meeting-notifications",
                         o =>
                         {
                             o.HttpMessageHandlerFactory = _ => Server?.CreateHandler();
                         })
              ---->  .AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol()
                     .Build();
```

Comment: Wow, i was pulling my hairs for hours with this one. Worked for me too.